# Adding the characters of two strings together

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def merge(string1, string2):        
    print( "".join(i for j in zip(string1, string2) for i in j))
```

When I run `merge("big","small")` the output is `bsimga`, I want the code to output `bsimgall`.

How can I add the characters from both strings in an alternating fashion even if the strings are not the same length?

Answer (score 2):

`zip()` will only produce pairs until the *shortest* iterable is exhausted. Use [`itertool.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate onwards and use a fill value to pad out the shorter string. Use an empty string to pad:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def merge(string1, string2):        
    print("".join(i for j in zip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue='') for i in j))
```

You can leave the joining to `print()`:

```
def merge(string1, string2):        
    print(*(i for j in zip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue='') for i in j), sep='')
```

and you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the result:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def merge(string1, string2):        
    print(*chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue='')), sep='')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.